# How can send a contact form with special characters in it, using html mail in php?

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form with `Name`, `CompanyName` and `Enquiry`. When I submit form with html entities in `Enquiry` field (say `<a href="link-to-page">Link</a>` Or `<script>alert('Hello World!');</script>`). It appears in the mail like, `<a href=\"link-to-page\">Link</a>` Or `<script>alert(\'Hello World!\');</script>`. Here both the quotes are escaped. How can I remove that escaping slashes?

I'm attaching snippet below.

```
//I have used htmlspecialchars() to get the html entities in mail as it is.

$senderName  =  htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['contactName'],ENT_QUOTES);
$senderCompany  = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['contactCompany'],ENT_QUOTES);
$senderEnquiry  = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['contactEnquiry'],ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: Is magic quotes enabled in your php configuration?

Comment: I think you should set the content type of the header as text/html

Answer (score 0):

Either You should set the content type of the header as text/html or please check the value while posting i think it is because of double quotes and single quotes problem.
For example see the below code:-

```
$new = htmlspecialchars("<script>alert(\'Hello World!\');</script>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // This will print output as <script>alert(\'Hello World!\');</script>
```

but if you will change the code as with double quote see below:-

```
$new = htmlspecialchars("<script>alert(\"Hello World!\");</script>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // This will print output as <script>alert("Hello World!");</script>
```

So please check if there is single and double quote problem while post

ing value via form